# Python: String will not convert to float

Tags: python, string

I wrote this program up a few hours ago:

```python
while True:
    print 'What would you like me to double?'
    line = raw_input('> ')
    if line == 'done':
        break
    else:
        float(line)              #doesn't seem to work. Why?
        result = line*2
        print type(line)         #prints as string?
        print type(result)       #prints as string?
        print " Entered value times two is ", result

print 'Done! Enter to close'
```

As far as I can tell, it should be working fine.The issue is that when I input a value, for example 6, I receive 66 instead of 12. It seems like this portion of code:

```python
float(line)
```

is not working and is treating line as a string instead of a floating point number. I've only been doing python for a day, so its probably a rookie mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`float(line)` does not convert in-place. It returns the `float` value. You need to assign it back to a float variable.

```
float_line = float(line)
```

**UPDATE:** Actually a better way is to first check if the input is a digit or not. In case it is not a digit `float(line)` would crash. So this is better -

```
float_line = None
if line.isdigit():
    float_line = float(line)
else:
    print 'ERROR: Input needs to be a DIGIT or FLOAT.'
```

Note that you can also do this by catching `ValueError` exception by first forcefully converting `line` and in `except` handle it.

```
try:
    float_line = float(line)
except ValueError:
    float_line = None
```

Any of the above 2 methods would lead to a more robust program.

Comment: This is the best solution. The name `line` is not appropriate for the resulting value. Even better would be `value = float(line)` and  then continue with that.

Answer (score 7):

`float()` returns a float, not converts it. Try:

```
line = float(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was just a rookie mistake. Thanks for the quick response, as I was refusing to go to sleep until I solved the issue.

Comment: In fact, it is not possible to convert the value "in-place" - the language doesn't work that way. In Python, variables don't have types, but values do, and those types don't change. You just create new values representing the "converted" result.

Answer (score 2):

`float(line)` doesn't change `line` at all, so it is still a string. You'll want to use `line = float(line)` instead.